# C++ setter/getter in one function?

Tags: c++

I've been doing a C++ course and one of the homeworks asks to implement an image class which has private member's rows_, cols_, data_. Where data is a vector of length rows X cols. They ask to implement a method whereby you can access the value of data_ given a row and column which is fine. However they also want to be able to assign a value to that position, as below:

```
int val = image.at(row, col);
Image.at(row, col) = 255;
```

I'm seems strange to me, if I returned a reference to the entry in data_ would the above functionality work? I feel you shouldn't allow Image.at(row,col) =255; as this breaks the encapsulation of data_?

Comment: Container classes are meant to give access to the objects stored in them, otherwise what would be the point of such a container?

Comment: Breaking encapsulation. Depends on the context. In this case no. I would say this is much better than defining separate `get()` and `set()` methods which break encapsulation in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite reasonable to return a reference to some internal data this way.

If you're *super* concerned, you could always return a wrapper object that only allows that single pixel to be operated on, but that's probably overkill.

What's *not* overkill however, is providing a const-correct function.  This is important if you have a const image object and want to read pixels from it.

So, you might have something like this:

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image()
        : mWidth(0)
        , mHeight(0)
    {}

    Image(int width, int height, const Pixel& color = {})
        : mWidth(width)
        , mHeight(height)
        , mBuffer(width * height, color)
    {}

    Pixel& at(int row, int col)
    {
        return mBuffer.at(row * mWidth + col);
    }

    const Pixel& at(int row, int col) const
    {
        return mBuffer.at(row * mWidth + col);
    }

private:
    int mWidth, mHeight;
    std::vector<Pixel> mBuffer;
};
```

Note that I've used `Pixel` here to show the more generic form of returning const-reference.  Of course, if you're just using integers, there's no need for the const version to return a reference at all -- it could just return `int`, while the non-const function would still return `int&`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes declare the method to return reference.

```
int & at(int row, int col) {return data[row * width + col];}
```

Assigning new value to the output will then rewrite the data in memory allocated somewhere inside the `data` member as that is where the reference is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

This is analogue to eg. [`std::vector at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)

Based on that this is how most standard containers and iterators work, I would say that it is fine. Remember *`const` correctness* though and provide const accessor as well.

Comment: Is the const accessor just like the method in paddy's answer? Will this method only return a const when the user of the class says, const Pixel = Image.at() etc. Then if they don't use const it will use the Pixel& at() method?

Comment: @Cr1064 the const referes to the object itself - not what its returned into

Comment: If that is so, how does the compiler know which at() method to use?